# Why is my Jenkins Doxygen make.bat not working?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, doxygen

I'm using Jenkins with the Doxygen Plugin.
When I generate the documentation of my project, doxygen generates a make.bat to convert a latex file to a pdf file.

When I run the make.bat by myself or the documentation is small (< 30mb), everything works fine. The Problem starts when I generate a documentation for a big project (pdf > 60mb). I execute make.bat in Jenkins with :

Call /wait make.bat

But jenkins just jumps to the next batch command when the pdf is around 30mb and then the pdf gets deleted.

Any solutions for this, that my make.bat is running properly ?
I don't get any errors

[image: Jenkins pdflatex command]

EDIT: 
The command pdflatex should generate the pdf file, but Jenkins just jumps to the next command. Like i said before, when i generate a smaller document or i do it manually by clicking the make.bat, everything works fine

**make.bat content:**

```
set Dir_Old=%cd%
cd /D %~dp0

del /s /f *.ps *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log *.out *.brf *.blg *.bbl refman.pdf

pdflatex refman
echo ----
makeindex refman.idx
echo ----
pdflatex refman

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=8
:repeat
set content=X
for /F "tokens=*" %%T in ( 'findstr /C:"Rerun LaTeX" refman.log' ) do set content="%%~T"
if !content! == X for /F "tokens=*" %%T in ( 'findstr /C:"Rerun to get cross-references right" refman.log' ) do set content="%%~T"
if !content! == X goto :skip
set /a count-=1
if !count! EQU 0 goto :skip

echo ----
pdflatex refman
goto :repeat
:skip
endlocal
makeindex refman.idx
pdflatex refman
cd /D %Dir_Old%
set Dir_Old=
```

**Jenkins Log with Big Project:**

```
C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project>exit 0 
[project] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins4374423821016124850.bat

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project>set latex_make_path=Build_Gen\latex\ 

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project>Build_Gen\latex\\make.bat

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project>set Dir_Old=C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project 

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project>cd /D C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex\ 

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>del /s /f *.ps *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log *.out *.brf *.blg *.bbl refman.pdf 
Could Not Find C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex\*.ps

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>pdflatex refman 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(refman.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.


C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>echo ---- 
----

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>makeindex refman.idx 
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file refman.idx...............................................done (43730 entries accepted, 716 rejected).
Sorting entries.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done (728591 comparisons).
Generating output file refman.ind...............................................done (73598 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in refman.ind.
Transcript written in refman.ilg.

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>echo ---- 
----

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>pdflatex refman 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(refman.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.


C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>set count=8 

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>set content=X 

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>for /F "tokens=*" %T in ('findstr /C:"Rerun LaTeX" refman.log') do set content="%~T" 

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>if !content! == X for /F "tokens=*" %T in ('findstr /C:"Rerun to get cross-references right" refman.log') do set content="%~T" 

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>if !content! == X goto :skip 

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>endlocal

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>makeindex refman.idx 
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file refman.idx..................done (14522 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries.....................................................................................................................................................done (218967 comparisons).
Generating output file refman.ind..................done (20218 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in refman.ind.
Transcript written in refman.ilg.

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>pdflatex refman 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(refman.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
```

The big pdf should be created here...but nothing happens

```
C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project\Build_Gen\latex>cd /D C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project

C:\build_server\Jenkins\workspace\project>set Dir_Old= 
[project] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins8022177968622333670.bat
```

Solution:

copy the make.bat into your jenkins bat. Change the directories and path if needed and add --pool-size=5000000 after every pdflatex refman command.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201323/discussion-on-question-by-heikoaz-why-is-my-jenkins-doxygen-make-bat-not-working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy the make.bat into your jenkins bat. Change the directories and path if needed and add --pool-size=5000000 after every pdflatex refman command.

Comment: Nice that you found a solution. Note that in the newer versions (don't know which version you are using) you can, most probably, use the setting `LATEX_CMD_NAME         = "pdflatex --pool-size=500000"` which results in "set LATEX_CMD=pdflatex --pool-size=500000
%LATEX_CMD% refman

Comment: I changed the pool size in the configuration file and even used the cmd commands to set the pool size...but even then the pool size was only 312......for me this is the only solution at the moment.